# Mapping values in a set of columns using a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, mapping

My problem: In a column set, replace the values in each column based on a chosen dictionary. I have two dictionaries, each with a set of keys (column names), and each key has two distinct values. In the end, sum the values of this set of columns and save them in a new column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,0,1,0,0,0,1], 'var2': [1,0,1,0,1,0,0], 'var3': [1,0,1,0,1,0,0]})

dict = { 
dict1 {"var1" : {0:0, 1:19}, "var2" : {0:0, 1:6}, "var3" : {0:0, 1:9}},
dict2 {"var1" : {0:0, 1:0}, "var2" : {0:0, 1:-1}, "var3" : {0:0, 1:-2}}
}

def get_values(df, dict):
        values = []
        for i in df.columns:
            np.where(df[i] == 1,
                     df[i].map(dict.key[dict]),
                     0)
            values = np.sum(df,axis=1).tolist()
        return values

dict1 = get_values(df, dict1)
dict2 = get_values(df, dict2)
```

I looked for similar posts involving mapping functions and nested dictionaries but couldn't find anything suitable for my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what I think you are asking:

```py
import numpy as np
def replaceAndSumValues(df, d):
    out = df.transform(lambda x, dct: np.where(x, dct[x.name][1], dct[x.name][0]), dct=d)
    return out.assign(sum=out.sum(axis=1))
```

**Explanation:**

Given an input dataframe and a nested dict that, for each column label, maps column values to replacement values, the function `replaceAndSumValues()` will:

- use `transform()` to iterate over the columns in the dataframe and call `np.where()` to replace the values in each column based on the nested dictionary for that column name
- create a new column `sum` which contains the sum of the values in all columns for each row.

---

Full test code:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,0,1,0,0,0,1], 'var2': [1,0,1,0,1,0,0], 'var3': [1,0,1,0,1,0,0]})
print(df)

dicts = { 
    'dict1': {"var1" : {0:0, 1:19}, "var2" : {0:0, 1:6}, "var3" : {0:0, 1:9}},
    'dict2': {"var1" : {0:0, 1:0}, "var2" : {0:0, 1:-1}, "var3" : {0:0, 1:-2}}
}
import numpy as np
def replaceAndSumValues(df, d):
    out = df.transform(lambda x, dct: np.where(x, dct[x.name][1], dct[x.name][0]), dct=d)
    return out.assign(sum=out.sum(axis=1))

df1 = replaceAndSumValues(df, dicts['dict1'])
print('df1:', df1, sep='\n')
df2 = replaceAndSumValues(df, dicts['dict2'])
print('df2:', df2, sep='\n')
```

Input:

```
   var1  var2  var3
0     1     1     1
1     0     0     0
2     1     1     1
3     0     0     0
4     0     1     1
5     0     0     0
6     1     0     0
```

Output:

```
df1:
   var1  var2  var3  sum
0    19     6     9   34
1     0     0     0    0
2    19     6     9   34
3     0     0     0    0
4     0     6     9   15
5     0     0     0    0
6    19     0     0   19
df2:
   var1  var2  var3  sum
0     0    -1    -2   -3
1     0     0     0    0
2     0    -1    -2   -3
3     0     0     0    0
4     0    -1    -2   -3
5     0     0     0    0
6     0     0     0    0
```

Comment: Great idea; I think I was overthinking the problem. Your solution worked fine. Thanks a lot.